# Difficult looking summation problem

Tags: number-theory, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \omega(n)(x^n - 2x^{2n} + (-x)^n) = \frac{2x^2}{1-x^4} $$
Where $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ and $\vert x \vert < 1$

Comment: Only looking difficult. It's either $\omega(2n) = \omega(n)$ or $\omega(2n) = \omega(n) + 1$ depending on the parity of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Writing $f(n)=\omega(n)(x^n-2x^{2n}+(-x)^n)$, rearrange as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) = \sum_{k\text{ odd}}\; \sum_{m=0}^\infty f(2^mk) $$
The inner sum then telescopes, taking the $\omega(k)$ with it and leaving just
$$ \sum_{k\text{ odd}} 2x^{2k} $$